# [MonoTouch][Bass.dll] Application crash "Attempting to JIT compile method .. while running with --aot-only"

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, jit, aot, bass

I faced a problem, that I can't solved for 3 days and you're my last hope.

My goal is to record sound with Bass.dll (there's special version of library for iPhone and version of .net wrapper for it; can be found here: un4seen.com)

On **simulator program works** (or seems to work properly). But when I tried to run it on the iPhone - I got this error:

"Attempting to JIT compile method '(wrapper native-to-managed) RecordingAudioHelloWorld.Player:recordingHandler (int,intptr,int,intptr)' while running with --aot-only."

error happens here:

```
RECORDPROC _recordingHandler = new RECORDPROC(recordingHandler);

_record = Bass.BASS_RecordStart(16000, 1, BASSFlag.BASS_SPEAKER_RIGHT, _recordingHandler, IntPtr.Zero); // <-- ERROR!!!

private int recordingHandler (int handle, IntPtr buffer, int length, IntPtr user)
{
//....
}
```

As I read here, on SO, I changed Linker behavior to "Link SDK assemblies only", but it has no effect.

Is there anything that I could do with it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to add the [MonoPInvokeCallback](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=T%3aMonoTouch.MonoPInvokeCallbackAttribute) attribute to your recordingHandler function. Note that you also need to make the function static.  `YourDelegateType` should be the delegate type you defined in C# that corresponds to the signature of this method.

```
[MonoPInvokeCallback (typeof(YourDelegateType)]
private static int recordingHandler (int handle, IntPtr buffer, int length, IntPtr user)
{
// ...
}
```

Comment: After adding

    [MonoPInvokeCallbackAttribute(typeof(_Ov_fopen))]
    [DllImport("__Internal", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "ov_fopen")]
    public static extern unsafe int ov_fopen([In()] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string path, ref File vf);

Delegate:

    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    delegate int _Ov_fopen(string path,ref File file);

Gives me a another error

`Error MT3001: Could not AOT the assembly '/XXX/obj/iPhone/Debug/build-iphone5.2-8.1.1/mtouch-cache/Build/BindingLibrary.dll' (MT3001)` @Rolf Bjarne Kvinge